# Fighting python type annotations

Tags: python, mypy

I have a very simple class that inherits from `requests.Session`. The code currently looks like:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

from typing import Any, Optional, Union, cast

default_gutendex_baseurl = "https://gutendex.com/"


class Gutendex(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, baseurl: Optional[str] = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.baseurl = baseurl or default_gutendex_baseurl

    def search(self, keywords: str) -> Any:
        res = self.get("/books", params={"search": keywords})
        res.raise_for_status()
        return res.json()

    def request(
        self, method: str, url: Union[str, bytes], *args, **kwargs
    ) -> requests.Response:
        if self.baseurl and not url.startswith("http"):
            url = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.baseurl, url)

        return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
```

I'm having a hard time making `mypy` happy with the `request` method.

The first challenge was getting the parameters to validate; setting
`url: Union[str, bytes]` was necessary to match the type annotation in
`types-requests`. I've just thrown up my hands on getting `*args` and
`**kwargs` correct, because the only solution appears to be
reproducing the individual parameter annotations, but I'm happy to
leave that as it.

With the function signature dealt with, `mypy` is now complaining
about the call to `startswith`:

> example.py:23: error: Argument 1 to "startswith" of "bytes" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Union[bytes, Tuple[bytes, ...]]"

I can resolve that with an explicit `cast`:

```
        if not cast(str, url).startswith("http"):
            url = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.baseurl, url)
```

...but that seems like it's just introducing complexity.

And then it's unhappy with the call to `urllib.parse.urljoin`:

> example.py:24: error: Value of type variable "AnyStr" of "urljoin" cannot be "Sequence[object]"
> example.py:24: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Sequence[object]", variable has type "Union[str, bytes]")

I'm not really sure what to make of these errors.

I've fixed things for now by moving the explicit cast to the top of
the method:

```
      def request(
          self, method: str, url: Union[str, bytes], *args, **kwargs
      ) -> requests.Response:
          _url = url.decode() if isinstance(url, bytes) else url

          if not _url.startswith("http"):
              _url = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.baseurl, _url)

          return super().request(method, _url, *args, **kwargs)
```

But that feels like a hacky workaround.

So:

- I think I have the function signature as correct as I care to get
  it, but are the type annotations on `url` correct or are they
  incorrect and resulting in problems?
- What is going on with the errors around `urljoin`?

---

From the comments, this:

```
        if self.baseurl and not url.startswith(
            "http" if isinstance(url, str) else b"http"
        ):
```

Fails with:

> example.py:25: error: Argument 1 to "startswith" of "str" has incompatible type "Union[str, bytes]"; expected "Union[str, Tuple[str, ...]]"
> example.py:25: error: Argument 1 to "startswith" of "bytes" has incompatible type "Union[str, bytes]"; expected "Union[bytes, Tuple[bytes, ...]]"

Comment: The problem is that if `_url` is a `bytes` value, then `_url.startswith("http")` is an actual *runtime* error; it has to be `_url.startswith(b"http")`. The cast might make `mypy` happy, but it's going to fail at runtime if `_url` really is a `bytes` value.

Comment: I know that I'm never calling `request` with a  `bytes` value, so I'm less concerned about that possibility. I guess the correct way of handling that would be tossing in an `isinstance(bytes, url)` and decoding as appropriate?

Comment: You could just declare the parameter as `str`. A subclass method doesn't have to accept all the same types as the parent class.

Comment: You don't even have to decode it, since `request` can already handle both. Just `_url.startswith("http" if isinstance(str, url) else b"http")` should suffice.

Comment: That is actually what I started with (declaring `url: str`), but in that case mypy -- even in non-strict mode -- complains: `error: Signature of "request" incompatible with supertype "Session"`

Comment: @Barmar For static typing purposes it does. You can (I think) *expand* the set of types it accepts, but you can't restrict it.

Comment: Right. And if you pass the parameter along to `super()`, you can't expand it, either.

Comment: You could also write `if str(url).startswith(...)`

Comment: @Barmar Right, you can't pass it unexamined, but it's OK to accept a wider type. (Consider something like `for x in my_list: x.request("foo")`. As long as everything in in `my_list` can accept a string, it doesn't matter what else it can accept, because the caller can't make any assumptions about the expanded usage.)

Comment: I'm surprised that `url` can be `bytes` in the first place. The `requests` documentation doesn't actually say the type of the `url` parameter, I just assumed it was string.

Comment: (On the other end, you can restrict the return type of the override, because even if you are only returning certain subtypes of `Response`, the caller won't be surprised by what you return.)

Comment: If you don't call it with a `bytes` value, that's OK, but your type hints say you support either type being passed. You said `url` was a `str` or a `bytes`, but passing a `bytes` would cause a runtime error - `mypy` is right to complain, even if you say you never do that. The entire problem (all the errors) goes away if you set the type hint to be what you need it: `url` is a `str`, because your function only treats it as a `str` - why exactly do you want it to be `bytes` as well? "to match the type annotation in types-requests" - why is that a goal?

Comment: @Grismar You can't do that, because then you are restricting the type you accept in a way that is incompatible with being a `Session`. It's fine to raise an *exception* if you actually receive a `bytes` value at runtime, but from a static typing perspective, you still have to accept it in the first place.

Comment: @Grismar He's answered that: Since this is a subclass, and the superclass method declares the type of the parameter, it has to be compatible.

Comment: Exactly, so if you subclass something that needs to be able to deal with `bytes` - so should your code. No surprises. If you can't do that, you shouldn't just subclass it, or stub off the `bytes` logic, so it accepts it, but generates a nice runtime message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This resolves the entire issue:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

from typing import Union, cast

default_gutendex_baseurl = "https://gutendex.com/"


class Gutendex(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, baseurl: str = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.baseurl = baseurl or default_gutendex_baseurl

    def search(self, keywords: str) -> dict[str, str]:
        res = self.get("/books", params={"search": keywords})
        res.raise_for_status()
        return res.json()

    def request(
        self, method: str, url: Union[str, bytes], *args, **kwargs
    ) -> requests.Response:
        if isinstance(url, str):
            if not url.startswith("http"):
                url = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.baseurl, url)

            return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Gutendex does not support bytes type url arguments')
```

You can't just not deal with `bytes` if you say you accept it. Just raise an exception or do something nicer if `bytes` get passed. Or even just `pass` if you like living dangerously.

This code validates just fine in `mypy`.

What's a bit disappointing is that something like this doesn't validate:

```
        if not url.startswith("http"):
            url = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.baseurl, url if isinstance(url, str) else url.decode())
        return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
```

Even though there is no way `url.startswith` gets a `bytes` when it's a `str` or vice versa, it still won't validate. `mypy` can't validate through the runtime logic, so instead you're stuck doing something like:

```
    def request(
        self, method: str, url: Union[str, bytes], *args, **kwargs
    ) -> requests.Response:
        if isinstance(url, str):
            if not url.startswith("http"):
                url = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.baseurl, url)

            return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            if not url.startswith(b"http"):
                url = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.baseurl, url.decode())

            return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
```

Which supports both, but repeats the logic in an ugly fashion.

Comment: The updated code in the question -- which explicitly calls `url.decode()` to convert `bytes` to `str` -- already solves the problem. I'm not sure if that's more or less correct. My question was more about whether I was approaching things the right way, and it sounds like given the existing type annotations on the superclass method I'm stuck having to explicitly check for `bytes` vs `str` arguments.

Comment: This might be the better solution. In the extreme case, you don't necessarily know *how* `url` is encoded (latin-1, utf-8, cp-1252, something else?). Better to require the caller to decode it first.

Comment: You're right @larsks - that does make sense though. You're subclassing `Session`, which needs to be able to deal with both, since your session should always work when substituted for its super class, even if you don't intend to do that, so it needs to graciously handle `bytes`

Comment: ...but as @chepner said, there's no way to know the encoding of the `bytes` value, but I guess one handles that in the documentation ("...must be a UTF-8 encoded byte string...").

Comment: Correct - a way to enforce that would be to have a `UTF8Bytes` subclass of `bytes`, but the designers of the library decided against it (and I think that's wise, because that would close to the door to adding that support for other encodings later without a lot of problems)

Comment: +1 for taking a look at this. I guess I'm happy that my initial hacky solution wasn't necessarily any worse that what we've come up with :). This isn't the first time I've worked with type annotations, but was a surprisingly thorny problem. I'm still sad about the options for handling `**kwargs`; I wish there was a "just inherit the function signature from the superclass..." option.

Comment: Ah, I didn't bother reading the documentation. Then you are probably fine calling `decode`, since you can raise the same extension that `super().request` will probably raise if the encoding scheme isn't UTF-8.

Comment: @chepner no,I meant I could solve it by writing my *own* documentation. I don't think the requests docs are explicit one way or the other.